# Render html table in React with dynamic array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects that comes from an API, but the content of this array is dynamic.

[image: array]

I want to map this data to an HTML table in React, using the `array.map` function, but I don't know how I could access the `variable.property`.

For example:

```
 {
     array.map(data=> {
        <td>{data.DynamicProperty}</td>  

     })
 }
```

What should I put in **DynamicProperty** ?
Could anybody show to me what could be the better approach for this case?

Comment: Any table should have defined number of columns ? Is there any logic to compute columns in your data ?

Comment: @gautamits they don't have a defined number of columns. The API reads an uploaded file and returns the data of that file. The files can be different from each other, that's why it's dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data is dynamic, what I had to do was take the property names and storing in the component hook's state:

```
const [mappableFields, setMappableFields] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {        
    if (array && array.length > 0) {
        setMappableFields(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array[0]));            
    }
}, [array]);
```

Then I mapped the array and the mappableFields, creating the `<td>` by reading each data by it's key, like this:

```
{ array.map((data, index) => (    
       <tr key={index}>
       {
            mappableFields.map((header, idx) => (
                 <td key={idx}>{data[header]}</td>  

            ))
       }                                          
       </tr>                 
   ))                                                                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get all values within object using `Object.values` and then map over them to return table columns in case you have more than one keys in each object. Or you could simply return `<td>{Object.values(data)[0]}</td>` if you have only one key in each object

```
{
     array.map(data=> {
       return (
          <>
            {Object.values(data).map(val => <td>{data}</td>)}
          </>
       )

    })
 }
```

Comment: What should I put in the DynamicProperty ? I don't know what is the property name since it's dynamic

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Updated the answer. You don't need to access by any key

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried your approach but that didn't work well. The Page does not render (and starts to consume a lot of memory)

Comment: When you say you want to render the data in a table, do you mean that each object within the array will have the same set of keys?

Comment: I had to add a key in each <td> with the index of each element of the array (eslint was alerting), but that didn't help